# Problemas de enconde en YII2

Tags: php, yii

Les platico primeramente mi escenario. Estoy utilizando la librería de SAP RFC en YII2 donde estoy importando una tabla del ERP de SAP a mi programa PHP. 
El problema es que al imprimir una variable que contiene acentos no me los esta imprimiendo correctamente, me pone algo como esto 'librer#a'. Al ver el formato de la variable con `mb_detect_encoding()` me aparece que es de tipo ASCII, no se si esto ayude en algo. Ya intenté con `utf8_encode()` y meta. 
¿Alguna recomendación?
Por el momento solo tengo en mente hacer esto por lado de ABAP, cosa que su me ha funcionado pero se me hace innecesario ya que lo mejor sería arreglarlo por el lado de PHP.

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX:
'[á]' IN wa_header-justif WITH '&aacute;',
'[é]' IN wa_header-justif WITH '&eacute;',
'[í]' IN wa_header-justif WITH '&iacute;',
'[ó]' IN wa_header-justif WITH '&oacute;',
'[ú]' IN wa_header-justif WITH '&uacute;'.
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

ASCII es un subconjunto de UTF-8, así que, si un documento está es ASCII es realmente UTF-8. Al ser [ASCII](http://ascii.cl/es/) un subconjunto significa que no soporta todos los caracteres que exiten, entre ellos las tíldes y la ñ. Cuando analiza la variable, la función devuelve ASCII ya que una palabra como "librer#a" todos sus caracteres se encuentra en esta tabla.

El otro caso a considerar acá es con que 'collation' fue definido en la estructura de la base de datos de origen. Según entiendo SAP utiliza como motor de base de datos SQL Server y su collection por defecto es  Latin1_General. Una solución a intentar es en el archivo php donde se hace la impresión, al inicio pone la siguiente declaración

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Cuando vaya hacer la impresión de la variable utilizar la siguiente función:

```
print iconv("CP1252", "UTF-8", $nombre_de_variable);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario pero sigue sin funcionar :(

Answer (score 0):

> **[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php)(** `string $string` **[**, `int $flags` **[**, `string $encoding`  **[**, `bool $double_encode` **]]] )**
>
> Convierte todos los caracteres aplicables a entidades HTML

Las entidades HTML son las que describís en la pregunta: `&aacute;` `&Eacute;`, `&ntilde;`, etc.

```
$resultado = htmlentities( $texto, ENT_SUBSTITUTE );
```